# GeoJSON tiles regression in v3.5.0

Tags: geojson, openlayers-3

My vector tiles were rendered correctly up to version 3.4, but nothing is displayed in 3.5. There are no errors in the JS console. I haven't found any related changes in the most recent API. Is it a bug?

```
var tileVectorSource = new ol.source.TileVector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
      maxZoom: 19
   }),
   url: 'data/{z}/{x}/{-y}.json'
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: tileVectorSource,
   style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
         color: '#9db9e8'
      })
   })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
         source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayer
   ],
   view: new ol.View({
      center: [1877798, 6568203],
      zoom: 6
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run into a bug see also: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3750

The fix (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3747) will hopefully be in the upcoming 3.6 release